# Error in Azure logic app workflow when using inline java script action

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

i am creating an Azure logic app workflow. as a part of it, i have an array and i need to create a table, for each item in the array i need to have one row in the table. and finally send that table via email. i have tried the inline java script action with the below code. but i get error `InlineCodeScriptRuntimeFailure. The inline code action 'JavaScriptCode' execution failed, with error 'document is not defined'.` anyone knows how i can fix it? or is there any other way to do that?

```
var rows = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
    email: "xx@hotmail.com"
}, {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 50,
    email: "xxx@hotmail.com"
}, {
    name: "Son",
    age: 45,
    email: "xxxx@hotmail.com"
}];

var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    html+="<tr>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].name+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].age+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].email+"</td>";
    
    html+="</tr>";

}
html+="</table>";
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: LogicApps doesn't work with the browser DOM.  What are you trying to do exactly?  "Box" wouldn't exist in the LogicApps context even if you could integrate with the browser DOM.  I think we need some clarity on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: 'Sending html table as body in mail' Is this what you want?

Comment: Return table as string without using *document* object. So, replace ```document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;``` to ```return html;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have an array and i need to create a table, for each item in the array i need to have one row in the table. and finally send that table via email.

To achieve this follow below design:

[image]

**`Inline code modified at end a bit:`**

```
var rows = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
    email: "xx@hotmail.com"
}, {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 50,
    email: "xxx@hotmail.com"
}, {
    name: "Son",
    age: 45,
    email: "xxxx@hotmail.com"
}];

var html = "<table border='2|2'>";
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    html+="<tr>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].name+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].age+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+rows[i].email+"</td>";
    
    html+="</tr>";

}
html+="</table>";
return html;
```

**`Compose Action:`**

```
<style>
#testID table, table th, table td {border: 1px solid #0000FF}
</style>
<div id="testID">
@{body('Execute_JavaScript_Code')}
</div>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: thank you @RithwikBojja, that works for me :)